# UPDATE command property for asp:SqlDataSource does not recognize parameter values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

The error occurs when the `asp:ListView` object tries to call the update command built in to the datasource. Specifically the error states:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FirstName', table
>   'SqlCatalog.dbo.Members'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
>   The statement has been terminated

I'm using the following code in the `ItemUpdateEventHandler` to verify NULL's are not being inserted into fields that are set to NOT NULL.

```
protected void Members_VerifyChanges(Object sender, ListViewItemUpdateEventArgs eArgs)
{
    if(eArgs.NewValues["ID"] == null || eArgs.NewValues["FirstName"] == null || eArgs.NewValues["LastName"] == null)
    {
        eArgs.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the UPDATE command specified for the datasource:

```
UPDATE Members SET [ID]=original_ID, [Approved]=@App, [FirstName]=@First, [MiddleInitial]=@Mid, [LastName]=@Last WHERE ID=@original_ID
```

Since the event handler function does not cancel the UPDATE command I can be sure the NewValues dictionary has something other than NULL to be inserted into the FirstName field.

Here is the specific test case I have been working with.

```
Old Values
 ________________________________________________________________________________
|____ID____|____Approved____|____First Name____|____Initial____|____Last Name____|
|__1001____|______[x]_______|_______Test_______|_______A_______|______Test_______|

New Values
 ________________________________________________________________________________
|____ID____|____Approved____|____First Name____|____Initial____|____Last Name____|
|__1001____|______[x]_______|______Bruce_______|_______A_______|______Wayne______|
```

To me it seems like the NewValues Dictionary is not being added to the parameters but I don't know how I could check that. I've thought about manually creating and executing the update command in the event handler but that's a hack i'd prefer not to do.

Here is the asp markup for the SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="WaterFacultySqlDataSrc" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Approved], [FirstName], [MiddleInitial], [LastName] FROM Members ORDER BY [ID] DESC"
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Members] (ID, Approved, FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName VALUES (@ID, @App, @First, @Mid, @Last)"
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Members] SET [ID]=@original_ID, [Approved]=@App, [FirstName]=@First, [MiddleInitial]=@Mid, [LastName]=@Last WHERE ID=@original_ID"
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Members] WHERE ID=@original_ID">
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="App" Type="Boolean" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="First" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Mid" Type="Char" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Last" Type="String" />
</UpdateParameters>
/**For Brevity I've excluded the other commands parameters*/
```

and finally the markup for the ListView controller:

```
<asp:ListView ID="PendingUpdates" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="WaterFacultySqlDataSrc" OnItemUpdating="Members_VerifyChanges">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="PendingUpdatesTable" runat="server">
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                    <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" 
                    style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">

                        <tr id="TableHeaders" runat="server" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
                             <th id="ApproveOrDeny" runat="server">
                                 Approve/Deny</th>
                             <th id="WF_ID_Header" runat="server">
                                 ID</th>
                             <th id="Approved_Header" runat="server">
                                 Approved</th>
                             <th id="First_Header" runat="server">
                                 First Name</th>
                             <th id="Middle_Header" runat="server">
                                 Initial</th>
                             <th id="Last_Header" runat="server">
                                 Last Name</th>
                         </tr>
                         <tr ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Edit_Button" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"/>
                <asp:Button ID="Delete_Button" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ID_Val" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Approve_Val" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Approved") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="First_Val" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Middle_Val" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MiddleInitial") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Last_Val" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Save_Button" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save"/>
                <asp:Button ID="Cancel_Button" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ID_Val" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:checkBox ID="Approve_Val" runat="server" checked='<%# Bind("Approved") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:textBox ID="First_Val" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:textBox ID="Middle_Val" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MiddleInitial") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:textBox ID="Last_Val" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </EditTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but changing the names of 2 of the parameters fixed this error.

```
UPDATE Members SET [ID]=original_ID, [Approved]=@App, [FirstName]=@FirstName, [MiddleInitial]=@Mid, [LastName]=@LastName WHERE ID=@original_ID}
```

I'm guessing Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 is parsing First and Last as keywords to indicate the chronological First and Last parameters rather than the parameters named First and Last. I've not been able to confirm that, but I'll keep digging and post the answer when I find it.